# I want to compare the text value from an Rest API with the Web Application element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jira-rest-api

I wrote a code like this to read the JSON array object value:

Content is like this "

```
jQuery19108586557654813183_1477636156780({
"current": {
    "all": {
        "android": [{
            "self": {
                "un": 86,
                "in": 2382,
                "ri": 756
            }
        }, {
            "Facebook": {
                "un": 168,
                "in": 570,
                "cpi": 452.59000000000015,
                "ri": 301
            }
        }, {
            "CPI_1_Network": {
                "un": 203,
                "in": 539,
                "ri": 375,
                "cpi": 401.2800000000001
            }
        }, {
            "Instagram": {
                "in": 854,
                "ri": 34,
                "un": 9,
                "cpi": 14.239999999999998
            }
        }, {
            "Ad-Network-2": {
                "in": 592,
                "un": 89,
                "cpi": 150.10999999999999
            }
        }, {
            "Top-shoppers": {
                "in": 892,
                "cpi": 12.500000000000002,
                "un": 12,
                "ri": 35
            }
        }],
        "ios": [{
            "CPI_1_Network": {
                "un": 55,
                "ri": 97,
                "in": 140,
                "cpi": 98.38999999999996
            }
        }, {
            "Ad-Network-2": {
                "un": 17,
                "in": 137,
                "cpi": 27.279999999999994
            }
        }, {
            "Instagram": {
                "cpi": 7.8500000000000005,
                "ri": 7,
                "in": 197,
                "un": 2
            }
        }, {
            "Top-shoppers": {
                "in": 207,
                "ri": 8,
                "un": 4,
                "cpi": 4.08
            }
        }, {
            "self": {
                "in": 567,
                "cpi": 1.21,
                "un": 24,
                "ri": 198
            }
        }, {
            "Facebook": {
                "in": 142,
                "un": 42,
                "ri": 69,
                "cpi": 103.86
            }
        }]
    },
    "androidTotal": 7330,
    "iosTotal": 1769,
    "totalUninstall": 711,
```

"i want to read this value content"
        "totalUniqueInstall": 7219,
        "totalUniqueUninstall": 711
    },
    "previous": {
        "androidTotal": 4156,
        "iosTotal": 1063,
        "totalUninstall": 1120
    }
    })

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL("url content ");

  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

 if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException(" HTTP error code : " +      conn.getResponseCode());
        }

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(url.openStream());
 String entireResponse = new String();
 while (scan.hasNext())
 entireResponse += scan.nextLine();
 System.out.println("Response is  : " + entireResponse);
 scan.close();

 entireResponse =entireResponse.substring(entireResponse.indexOf("{"),   entireResponse.length() - 1);

 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(entireResponse.trim());
  JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("current");
  String uniqueInstalls = String.valueOf(obj.get("totalUniqueInstall"));
  System.out.println(uniqueInstalls);

        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But i am getting a Run Time Exception in Java 
     `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["current"] is not a JSONArray.`

Please help me on this.

Comment: can you provide the sample expected JSON content ?

Comment: You can use the URL content. click it in a new tab.

Comment: FAILED: installsWithAPI
org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["current"] is not a JSONArray.
 at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:622)
 at com.AppICE_TC_DemoApp.DemoApp_DashBoard.installsWithAPI(DemoApp_DashBoard.java:54)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: If you go through the above url, there is a content like this " "totalUniqueInstall":7219". i want to print that value in the console.

Comment: current is a json object not an array

Comment: @RamaSwamyS r u still facing the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Because the object in current node is a `JSONObject`, it's not an `JSONArray`

```
int uniqueInstalls = obj.getJSONObject("current").getInt("totalUniqueInstall");
String uniqueInstallString = "" + uniqueInstalls;
```

or:

```
String uniqueInstalls = obj.getJSONObject("current").get("totalUniqueInstall").toString();
```

Comment: Now i am getting this exception "org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["totalUniqueInstall"] not a string."

Comment: As you mentioned in the before comment. Based on that, I changed the return type to an Int value. The code shipment is working fine and returning the value. The code is " int uniqueInstalls = obj.getJSONObject("current").getInt("totalUniqueInstall"); " But raised with another problem. I need to compare the value with the Dashboard. Which has a return type of String. But the present value is Int type.

Comment: @RamaSwamyS per your need, anyway, it's better to compare in `int`

Answer (score 0):

As the exception clearly says `current` element is NOT an array as you are expecting,

The problem is with the line `JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("current");`
which needs to be changed.

Assuming that `totalUniqueInstall` is `int` type, you can refer the below code:

```
String uniqueInstalls = obj.getJSONObject("current").getInt("totalUniqueInstall");
```

Comment: I am cleared with my doubt, Thanks for helping @Danh. My code shipment is working fine.